# Is it possible to stop a user from editing a certain part of the Elementor Pro Layout?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, restriction

Asking what the title says. I made a plugin where the Title, Date and Link is automatically added on a new Elementor Page. I only want one section of the page to be edited by a user with no admin privileges, is it possible?

[image: 1]

If you look at the screenshot, the content containing "Researchers and Industrial Leaders..." is the only one I need to be able to get edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with ACF or JetEngine you could dynamically connect that section to an editable section in the dashboard... that way your user stays out of Elementor but can edit sections on the site.

That's how I do it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).